# Thumb On Slider Not Moving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uislider

Hi there I have an issue with making my vertical slider move in my ios app. I think there's an issue because it's a subview of the view I have represented as a bar.

bar image:

[image]

slider part of view:

[image]

I try moving the slider outside the view because then it can work but it completely changes the position of my vertical slider and I don't want that. Is there a way I can have it be at the same position yet not be in the view?

Comment: A view that is outside its superview cannot (normally) be touched. That might be situation you're in.

Comment: You'll need to show what you're doing to make this a "vertical" slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just can't drag the slider into a view when working with storyboard.